# Subtract from line and move to next

Tags: c#, linq

I want to subtract from the line with oldest date and where counter > 0, and when it reaches 0 I want to subtract from the next oldest line with the same itemId and do some other updates on other tables.

My question is if there is a better way to do it and if my code has no bad efficiency. If it breaks down, will the code do a rollback? Do I need try/catch? Please if any suggestions, provide with some code. 
Here is my code:

```
public static int insertOrder(Order order)
    {
        using (var db = new AWarehouseDataClassesDataContext())
        {
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
                tblOrder row = generateOrderToBeInserted(order);
                db.tblOrders.InsertOnSubmit(row);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                order.orderId = row.OrderId;

                foreach(var x in order.insertList)
                {
                    int qt = x.qty;
                    while (qt > 0)
                    {
                        var line = db.tblInsertLines.First(r => r.ItemId == x.itemId && r.Counter > 0);
                        int c = line.Counter;
                        for (int a = c; a > 0 && qt > 0; a--)
                        {
                            line.Counter = line.Counter - 1;
                            qt--;
                        }
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                    }
                    tblOrderLine orderLine = generateOrderLine(order, x);
                    db.tblOrderLines.InsertOnSubmit(orderLine);
                    db.SubmitChanges();

                    var item = db.tblItems.Single(i => i.ItemId == x.itemId);
                    item.Qty = item.Qty - x.qty;
                    item.LastUpdate = order.orderDate;
                    item.UpdatedBy = order.user;
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
                ts.Complete();
                return order.orderId;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is a better fit @ [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What you mean by better fit ?

Comment: Obviously `for loop` can be replaced with `linq`.

Comment: Lei Yang, can you help with code example